# Kinect depth Segmentation frame rate

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I am new to kinect project
And I am implementing a depth threshold when distance is greater than 400mm

```
for (UINT y = 0; y < pImg->rows; ++y)
{
    // Get row pointers for Mats
    const USHORT* pDepthRow = depth->ptr<USHORT>(y);

    for (UINT x = 0; x < pImg->cols; ++x)
    {
        USHORT raw_depth = pDepthRow[x];
        SHORT realDepth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(raw_depth);
        // If depth value is valid, convert and copy it
       if (raw_depth != 65535)
        {
            if(realDepth >400 ) //greater than 400mm
            {
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[0] = 255;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[1] = 255;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[2] = 255;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[3] = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[0] = 0;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[1] = 0;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[2] = 0;
                pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[3] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

It seems get the correct result but reduces the frame rate massively.
When I want to get rid of the loop by using the cv::inRange, but this function only support 8U1C when the raw depth is 16U.
So what else can I use to segment the  depth according to the real distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to improve performance by storing a reference to the pixel.
Change this:

```
if (realDepth > 400) //greater than 400mm
{
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[0] = 255;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[1] = 255;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[2] = 255;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[3] = 255;
}
else
{
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[0] = 0;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[1] = 0;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[2] = 0;
    pImg->at<Vec4b>(y,x)[3] = 0;
}
```

To this:
(I don´t know what `T` is because I dont know what `pImg` is.
`T` should be equal to the return value of the `at` method. I assume it is `Vec4b`.)

```
T& pixel = pImg->at<Vec4b>(y, x); // probably Vec4b& pixel = ..
if (realDepth > 400) //greater than 400mm
{
    pixel[0] = 255;
    pixel[1] = 255;
    pixel[2] = 255;
    pixel[3] = 255;
}
else
{
    pixel[0] = 0;
    pixel[1] = 0;
    pixel[2] = 0;
    pixel[3] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it really boost the fps from 8 to 15!